Plotly Express - Scatter Plot - X axis issue (zoom issue?)
I am trying to create a plot with time slider for the checkpoints a marathon runner has crossed with respect to time.
The code is as below -
fig = px.scatter(data_frame=marathon_data, x="Check_Point", animation_frame="Record_Time",
                     color="RunnerNumber")

The plot is not showing all the Check Points in the x axis and I get the plot as below. Zooming out and in and Autoscaling buttons also do not work.

Sample Data is as below
RunnerNumber    Check_Point Record_Time
5187    864 2024-04-16 04:42:00
5187    421216  2024-04-16 04:45:00
5187    421281  2024-04-16 04:46:00
5187    421230  2024-04-16 04:47:00
5187    421284  2024-04-16 04:47:00
5187    421233  2024-04-16 04:48:00
5187    8453    2024-04-16 04:54:00
5187    8456    2024-04-16 05:04:00
5187    9125    2024-04-16 05:24:00
5187    421490  2024-04-16 05:36:00
5187    421491  2024-04-16 05:36:00
5187    8881    2024-04-16 06:06:00
5187    9629    2024-04-16 06:19:00
5187    8683    2024-04-16 06:38:00
5187    9653    2024-04-16 06:38:00
5187    9654    2024-04-16 06:38:00
5187    8995    2024-04-16 06:57:00
5187    9136    2024-04-16 06:57:00
5187    8854    2024-04-16 06:58:00
5187    8883    2024-04-16 06:59:00
5187    421236  2024-04-16 06:59:00
5187    421237  2024-04-16 06:59:00
5187    421454  2024-04-16 06:59:00
5187    819 2024-04-16 07:25:00
5187    421449  2024-04-16 07:25:00
5187    422501  2024-04-16 07:29:00
5187    422583  2024-04-16 07:39:00
5187    422584  2024-04-16 07:47:00
5187    422585  2024-04-16 07:47:00
5187    683 2024-04-16 07:48:00
5187    422010  2024-04-16 07:50:00
5187    422013  2024-04-16 07:51:00
5187    422020  2024-04-16 07:52:00
5187    422021  2024-04-16 07:52:00
5187    422192  2024-04-16 07:55:00
5187    422194  2024-04-16 07:55:00
5187    665 2024-04-16 07:59:00
5187    421450  2024-04-16 07:59:00
5187    422182  2024-04-16 07:59:00

I have tried autosize=True and other aspects but the plot is not displayed properly. I have also tried fig.update_xaxes(type="category", tickvals=check_points) where check_points is the list of Check Points.
Both RunnerNumber and Check_Points are string variables.

The range of the x-axis must be given. Please add the following code. fig.update_xaxes(range=[marathon_data.Check_Point.min(),marathon_data.Check_Point.max()])

Including an animation frame basically creates a filter per slider position. So for each position of the slider it takes all datapoints corresponding to that (time) value and shows the plot.
Your table probably has one Check_Points value per timestamp. So in each frame (corresponding with one time value) it only shows one datapoint.

This issue happens because you are using categorical data on the xaxis. It has been addressed here, but in your situation you can use factorize to obtain a numeric representation of the distinct checkpoints and then set tickmode='array' with the appropriate tickvals and ticktext. You can also fix the zoom window by specifying the xaxis range :
df['x'] = pd.factorize(df['Check_Point'])[0]
df['y'] = 0 # specify y to avoid scale jumps across frames

fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', animation_frame="Record_Time", color='RunnerNumber')

n = df['Check_Point'].nunique()
room = n / 20

fig.update_xaxes(
    tickmode = 'array',
    tickvals = df['x'],
    ticktext = df['Check_Point'],
    range=[0-room, n-1+room]
)

fig.show()

